# iOS Clumsy UISearchBar Animation

Tags: ios, animation, uisearchbar

I am trying to animate the UISearchBar using the

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

delegate methods, but my implementation of the latter seems to lead to a [clumsy animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhhq4a6wj4ndxji/normal.mov) (slow animation version [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mir1ikkpwresph/slowmo.mov)). My delegate implementation is shown below (I changed the duration to generate the second video). Is there any way to fix this?

It may be important to note that `navigation` is a standalone UINavigationBar (I did not use a UINavigationController for this).

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^ {
                     navigation.alpha = 1;

                     CGRect newTableBounds = chatList.frame;
                     newTableBounds.size.width -= 40; //newBounds.size.width -= 215; to contract
                     newTableBounds.origin.x += 40;
                     newTableBounds.origin.y += 40;
                     chatList.frame = newTableBounds;

                     CGRect rootFrame = self.ddParent.rootViewController.view.frame;
                     rootFrame.origin.x += 40;
                     self.ddParent.rootViewController.view.frame = rootFrame;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
    return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adjusting the search bar frame within the animation. The adjustment is taking place immediately, and then the other items are animated. Move it into the animation block, and everything should be good.

Comment: I've tried moving that code snippet but it doesn't change the animation at all. Interestingly, deleting it also has no effect.

Comment: What happens if you completely remove the animation block? Does the search bar still jump?

Comment: When I removed the animation block completely, it didnt jump, but it also didnt reposition appropriately. I also tried executing the code within the animation block without an animation, and the searchbar still jumped.